# How to Disable UIButton with a Timer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I would like to make the button disable for 10 second before letting user to click the button. Any idea how to do that?

Below attached the method of the button:

```
partial void CheckOutBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        if(condition)
        CheckOutBtn.Hidden = true;
        else
            new UIAlertView("Great Job!", "You had checked out.", null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
```

Comment: What is the disabling function? ie. When the user clicks on something else, disable the button then wait 10secs and enable it, or....?

Comment: My expected output will be when user enter the page, the check out button will be disable for 10 second, after that only appear and let user to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when user enter the page, the check out button will be disable for 10 second, after that only appear and let user to click it.

You are saying "disable" and "appear", two different things, but you can use the GCD to execute a block of code after a delay.

Something like this in your ViewController's `ViewDidLoad()` override will get you started:

```
~~~
//? button.Hidden = true;
button.Enabled =  false;

var delay = new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(delay, () =>
{
    button.Enabled = true;
    //? button.Hidden = false;
});

button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    // perform some action... 
};
~~~
```

Comment: It works, Thanks! but I want it to be the negative way, which is disappear first for 10 second, after 10 second only appears. On the other word, the button should be invisible when user enter the page, only after 10 second he stay on the page, the button will only appear.

Comment: My mistakes T.T . I am finally able to make it work as I expected, thank you so much for the help mate !